# Captures count is always zero

Tags: c#, regex, capture

I've got a problem. I use following regular expression:

---

```
Pattern =
  (?'name'\w+(?:\w|\s)*), \s*
  (?'category'\w+(?:\w|\s)*), \s*
  (?:
      \{ \s*
          [yY]: (?'year'\d+), \s*
          [vV]: (?'volume'(?:([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))+), \s*
      \} \s*
      ,? \s*
  )*
```

with `IgnorePatternWhitespaces` option.
Everything seemed fine in my application until I debugged it & encountered a problem.

---

```
var Year = default(UInt32);
// ...
if((Match = Regex.Match(Line, Pattern, Options)).Success)
{
    // Getting Product header information
    Name = Match.Groups["name"].Value;

    // Gathering Product statistics
    for(var ix = default(Int32); ix < Match.Groups["year"].Captures.Count; ix++)
    {
       // never get here
       Year = UInt32.Parse(Match.Groups["year"].Captures[ix].Value, NumberType, Culture);
    }
}
```

So in the code above.. In my case Match is always successful. I get proper value for `Name` but when turn comes to `for` loop program flow just passes it by. I debugged there's no `Captures` in `Match.Groups["year"]`. So it is logical behavior. But not obvious to me where I'm wrong. Help!!

There is a previous connected post [Extract number values enclosed inside curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163017/values-extraction-problem-regular-expressions-c) I made.

Thanks!

### EDIT. Input Samples

```
Sherwood, reciever, {y:2008,V:5528.35}, {y:2009,V:8653.89}, {y:2010, V:4290.51}
```

- I need to capture `2008`, `5528.35`, `2009`, `8653.89`, `2010`, `4290.51` values and operate with them as named groups.

### 2D EDIT

I tried using `ExplicitCapture` Option and following expression:

```
(?<name>\w+(w\| )*), (?<category>\w+(w\| )*), (\{[yY]:(?<year>\d+), *[vV]:(?<volume>(([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))+)\}(, )?)+
```

But that didn't help.

Comment: Could you add a few examples of the string you're trying to match?

Comment: The type of `Captures.Count` is non-nullable.  Do you mean it's zero, or you get an exception trying to access it, or what?

Comment: @Ben I can't achieve a successful match with my last expression (given in 2nd edit) and input (1st edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You could simplify by matching everything until the next comma: `[^,]*`.  Here's a full code snippet to match your source data:

```
var testRegex = new Regex(@"
    (?'name'[^,]*),\s*
    (?'category'[^,]*),\s*
    ({y:(?'year'[^,]*),\s*
    V:(?'volume'[^,]*),?\s*)*",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
var testMatches = testRegex.Matches(
    "Sherwood, reciev, {y:2008,V:5528.35}, {y:2009,V:8653.89}, {y:2010, V:4290.51}");
foreach (Match testMatch in testMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", testMatch.Groups["name"].Value);
    foreach (var capture in testMatch.Groups["year"].Captures)
        Console.WriteLine("    Year = {0}", capture);
}
```

This prints:

```
Name = Sherwood
    Year = 2008
    Year = 2009
    Year = 2010
```

Comment: Ok. I understand that. But that doesn't resolve question about named groups and capturing them.

Comment: Regex failed at first string of input. How do I examine where to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a comma:

```
, \s* \}
```

which should be optional (or omitted?):

```
,? \s* \}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expound on what MRAB said:

```
(?'name'
    \w+
    (?:
       \w|\s
    )*
),
\s* 
(?'category'
     \w+
     (?:
         \w|\s
     )*
),
\s* 
(?:
      \{ 
          \s*
          [yY]:
          (?'year'
               \d+
          ),
          \s*
          [vV]:
          (?'volume'
               (?:
                   (     # Why do you need capturing parenth's here ?
                     [1-9][0-9]*
                     \.?
                     [0-9]*
                   )
                 |
                   (
                     \.[0-9]+
                   )
               )+
          ),        # I'm just guessing this comma doesent match input samples
          \s*
      \}
      \s*
      ,?
      \s*
)*


Sherwood, reciever, {y:2008,V:5528.35}, {y:2009,V:8653.89}, {y:2010, V:4290.51}
```